# How do I get the index of multiple occurrences of the same character in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this function that receives a word and lists the index of each capital letter:

```
def capitals(word):
    print word
    lst = []
    for i in word:
        if i.isupper():
            lst += [word.index(i)]
    return lst
```

When all capital letters in word are different, it runs fine. Example:

> capitals("AuIkkdjsiP") returns [0,2,9]

However, if a string has duplicate capitals, this happens:

> capitals("AuAskdjfIsjUsdhA") returns [0,0,10,0]

How do I get the index of the other occurrences of the char "A" when iterating the string?

Comment: Use `enumerate()` and iterate over both index and the character.

Comment: After `import re`, `[ match.start() for match in re.finditer('[A-Z]', "AuAskdjfIsjUsdhA") ]` ==> `[0, 2, 8, 11, 15]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to handle repeating characters, you can also use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
def capitals(word):
    return [i for i, ch in enumerate(word) if ch.isupper()]
```

`ch` is each character in the word, `i` is the index of the char.

On another note, if you want to add a single item to a list you should append not `+=`, if you have multiple elements to add it makes sense to `+=/extend` but for a single element just append :

```
def capitals(word):
    print word
    lst = []
    for i,ch in enumerate(word):
        if ch.isupper():
            lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

Comment: Thanks, that's right what I was looking for!

Comment: No worries, you're welcome, no idea why you got downvoted, you supplied your code and a good attempt.

Comment: I've seen it happen sometimes, as soon as someone flags a post as a duplicate, people automatically start down voting without even reading the question :/