# Getting the position of an item in a list from an input (Python)

Tags: python, list

I have a list with words in it. I want to get the position of the word in the sentence that the user asks for. (I am using python)
For example if I had the sentence: `"Hello world how are you doing today world?"` `'World'` occurs in the first and eighth positions. If a user wants to know the positions of the word `'world'` in that sentence it would print `"The word world is in position 1 and 8"`. I am aware of the `enumerate` method but cannot get it to work with an input or an `elif` statement. I want to get the position(s) of any word in the sentence no matter how many times the word occurs.

Comment: `word = input("Enter word: ").strip().lower()` and `answer = [i for i,w in enuemrate(sentence.lower().split()) if w==word]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget nope, mind the "?".

Comment: @timgeb: not sure I follow

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31908627)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget your code was my first attempt too, but it does not find 'world' in 'world?' but the specs say it should.

Comment: @timgeb: try the edit

Comment: @inspectorG4dget gives me the result `[1]`.

Comment: @timgeb: that's because `world?` and `world` are not the same. You'd therefore have to include ONLY the elements of `string.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I know? The specifications in the question say it should find 'world' in 'world?' regardless. That's why we need a regex.

Comment: you shouldn't need a regex. Just filter your sentence like this: `sentence = ''.join([char for char in sentence if char in string.ascii_lowercase + '  '])`. Don't forget to `import string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sentence = "Hello world how are you doing today world?".lower()
searchword = input("Enter word:  ").lower()

newsentence = ''

for character in sentence:
    if character.islower() or character == ' ': newsentence += character

answer = [position for position, word in enumerate(newsentence.split()) if searchword == word]

print(answer)
```

Comment: I have used your method but it uses the wrong positions. For example 0 when it should be 1. I know why this occurs. I have tried adding 1 to answer but that just caused an error. I was wondering if you know a solution?

Comment: List start at position 0. Hello is in position 0 in "Hello world". I won't recommend it but if it is necessary I would just change answer to below.

answer = [position + 1 for position, word in enumerate(newsentence.split()) if searchword == word]

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the words using a regular expression, then use `enumerate()` in a list comprehension to find the indexes of the word:

```
>>> import re
>>> s =  "Hello world how are you doing today world?"
>>> word = input("Enter a word: ").lower()
Enter a word: world
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(re.findall(r'\w+', s)) if v == word]
[1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence, the word `"world"` appears in position 1 and 7.

```
> sentence = "Hello world how are you doing today world?"
> word = input("Enter word:  ").lower()
> answer = [i for i, w in enumerate(sentence.lower().split()) if word in w]
> answer
> [1, 7]
```

This will work regardless of case or punctuation.

Comment: This will also print the positions of words for which the word is a substring, e.g. `"worlds"`.

Comment: or `"otherworldly"`, should these words really be counted?

Comment: Yup.  The re solutions look good, or if R.McEvoy doesn't want to use re, the @Michael solution looks good.

Answer (score -1):

With `re.finditer` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='Hello world how are you doing today world?'
>>> word='world'
>>> [i for i, w in enumerate(re.finditer('\w+', s)) if w.group()==word]
[1, 7]
```

We (greedily) find every sequence of characters delimited by non-word characters, iterate over it, and store the index if it is equals to the target word.

Answer (score -1):

```
 import re
 s='Hello world how are you doing today world?'
 word='world'
 [i for i, w in enumerate(re.findall('\w+', s)) if w.lower() == word.lower()]
```